# Cannot implicitly convert type bool to System.DateTime (C#)

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to `convert` a `string to datetime to validate` if user input is actually a date.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type bool to System.DateTime.
```

I've been looking online for a while and can't find anything specific enough to help me understand.

Code:

> ```
>    public bool is21YearsOfAge(string argument)
>    {
>        DateTime _parsedDateArgument;
>        DateTime convertStringToDate = System.DateTime.TryParse(argument, out >_parsedDateArgument);
>
>        if (convertStringToDate > DateTime.Now)
>        {
>            //do something
>        }
>
>    }
> ```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the format of your date ?

Comment: Thanks for fixing my formatting (newbie here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) method returns a `bool` that informs you whether the parse was successful, rather than throwing an exception like the [`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx) method does.  Try doing this:

```
DateTime convertStringToDate;
bool isDate = DateTime.TryParse(argument, out convertStringToDate);
```

If `argument` is a date, `convertStringToDate` will contain that date as a `DateTime`.

Comment: Thanks, Dan (and everyone else who helped).

Answer (score 2):

DateTime.TryParse returns bool to indicate if parsing was successeful. So you should do

```
System.DateTime.TryParse(argument, out _parsedDateArgument);
DateTime convertStringToDate =_parsedDateArgument
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
DateTime convertStringToDate;

if(System.DateTime.TryParse(argument, out convertStringToDate))
{
    //Now you will have converted date in convertStringToDate
    if (convertStringToDate > DateTime.Now)
    {
       //do something
    }
}
else
{
    //argument not have a valid date
}
```

System.DateTime.TryParse will retrun true if, argument will have a valid date string to convert. and the converted date will be store in its out parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [documentation for `DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1) - it *returns* a `bool`, but has an *out* parameter for the parsed result:

```
DateTime dateTime;
bool success = DateTime.TryParse(text, out dateTime);
```

If `success` is false, that means the text couldn't be parsed. (So typically at this point you'd display an error to the user.)

You've already got the `out` parameter - why did you *expect* to end up with two different `DateTime` values (one as the return value and one from the `out` parameter)?

When you get an error like this, *always* read the documentation as the first step towards diagnosing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.TryParse do not return a DateTime value. It returns a bool indicating if it could parse it.

Instead use

```
DateTime convertStringToDate;
if(DateTime.TryParse(argument, out convertStringToDate)){
   //ok value is good
}else{
  //Not ok value is not good
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this instead,

```
DateTime _parsedDateArgument;
bool success = System.DateTime.TryParse(argument, out _parsedDateArgument);
```

Always remember that `Tryparse` always return boolean.

Answer (score 0):

TryParse returns a `bool`, use just `Parse` instead, or assign the out variable to the new you have:

```
System.DateTime.TryParse(argument, out _parsedDateArgument);
DateTime convertStringToDate = _parsedDateArgument;
```

or like this:

```
DateTime convertStringToDate = DateTime.Parse(argument);
```

Answer (score 0):

add the following namespace

```
using System.Globalization;
```

Create object of CultureInfo class

```
CultureInfo MyCI = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime convertStringToDate = System.DateTime.TryParse(argument.ToString("MM/dd/yy", MyCI), out _parsedDateArgument);
```